# Spring boot 2.2.7 migration breaks Jaxb unmarshal

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a Java 11 application that works perfectly fine with Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE, but it breaks when I upgrade to v2.2.7.RELEASE. The problem is that I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when reading the nested object:

```
jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringSource(xml)).getChild().foo();
```

I checked the SB release notes and this seems to be the breaking change: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21195

As migrating from Glassfish Jaxb 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 is a patch change, I would expect that this upgrade should require no changes from my side. I tried to check for some migration guide but found nothing at [jaxb-ri page](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/releases/tag/2.3.3-RI). Any idea would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in the JAXB reference implementation. If you haven't already done so, I would search the RI's [open issues](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues) for an existing report of your problem. If you don't find anything, I would then open an issue that describes your problem and includes a minimal sample that works with 2.3.2 and fails with 2.3.3.